# Since i used optionmenu from tkinter in python, debugging do not work anymore (in all skripts)

Tags: python, utf-8

The full error is here:

```
debugfile('C:/Users/Tom/.spyder-py3/pandatesttest.py', wdir='C:/Users/Tom/.spyder-py3')
> c:\users\tom\.spyder-py3\pandatesttest.py(1)<module>()
----> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      2 import pandas as pd
      3 import xlrd
      4 import numpy.matlib
      5 import numpy as np

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "c:\users\tom\.spyder-py3\pandatesttest.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  File "c:\users\tom\.spyder-py3\pandatesttest.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\bdb.py", line 88, in trace_dispatch
    return self.dispatch_line(frame)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\bdb.py", line 112, in dispatch_line
    self.user_line(frame)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\pdb.py", line 259, in user_line
    self.interaction(frame, None)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spyderpdb.py", line 143, in interaction
    self._cmdloop()

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spyderpdb.py", line 302, in _cmdloop
    self.cmdloop()

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\cmd.py", line 105, in cmdloop
    self.preloop()

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spyderpdb.py", line 254, in preloop
    self.set_spyder_breakpoints(pdb_settings['breakpoints'])

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spyderpdb.py", line 370, in set_spyder_breakpoints
    cond=condition)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\bdb.py", line 375, in set_break
    line = linecache.getline(filename, lineno)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\linecache.py", line 16, in getline
    lines = getlines(filename, module_globals)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\linecache.py", line 47, in getlines
    return updatecache(filename, module_globals)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\linecache.py", line 137, in updatecache
    lines = fp.readlines()

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 79: invalid continuation byte
```

I dont know what to do.
If i try to debug a code (start debug button) this error pop up.
I programmed a gui with tkinter. Since I accessed the object 'optionmenu' the error occurred by starting debugging. when I try to debug another script the error also comes

Comment: Your previous question got closed. Instead of copy-pasting the contents into a new post, you should address the issues (you partly had done that already) and ask for re-opening. Copy-paste posting is frowned upon here and it might get you banned from the site.

Comment: i didnt know that.